# Probability of n flipped coins falling back onto the same side

Tags: probability

For n number of coins, when flipped what is the probability that they all fall back onto the same side after a single flip?

Could anyone give any assistance with this question?
Thanks

Comment: The same side as what?

Comment: What is the probability for flipping one such coin?  The notion of "back onto the same side" is a little ambiguous.  Do you mean the same side it was on before flipping (regardless of the other coins), or do you mean all coins wind up showing the same side in the end?  Clear this up by editing your original post.

Comment: We have $2^n$ possible outcomes.  Only two of them is acceptable (all heads and all tails.)

Comment: @GNUSupporter presuming the question means "all coins fall the same", if one coin is flipped, the probablility is 1. But $2^1$ is 2.

Comment: @WeatherVane the number of possible outcomes is not the same as the probability-- you have to divide the former by the size of the probability space (heads or tails), which is again, 2.

Comment: @WeatherVane Any one of two possible outcomes satisfies trivially the quoted condition, so the probability is constant two over $2^1$, and we do get $1$ at the end.

Comment: For exam purposes, we can *assume* the coin is fair.  But it is really the case?  It's not written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Total Possible outcomes for n coins will be 2^n

So the probability that each coin will be flipped back to the same side will be 1/2.

for n coins, it will be 1/2^n.

Correct me, if I was wrong...

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please see the comments.  I suggest you not to post an answer to any questions which doesn't include enough work.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "What is the probability of flipping $n$ coins and getting the same result on all $n$ coins", the answer is:

$$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = \frac{2}{2^n}$$

because there are two ways to get the same result on all coins: all heads $HHHH\ldots H$ or all tails $TTTT\ldots T$. But the total number of different results is $2^n$; hence $2/2^n$ is the probability.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this empirical test using C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXCOINS    5
#define THROWS      10000

int main(void)
{
    int c, t, same, coins, face;
    for(coins = 1; coins <= MAXCOINS; coins++) {
        same = 0;
        for(t = 0; t < THROWS; t++) {
            face = rand() & 1;
            for(c = 1; c < coins; c++) {
                if(face != (rand() & 1))
                    break;
            }
            if(c == coins) {
                same++;
            }
        }
        printf("Coins=%d Throws=%d Same=%-5d Prob=%f, Guess=%f\n", 
            coins, THROWS, same, (double)same/THROWS, 2.0/pow(2, coins));
    }
}
```

Program output

```
Coins=1 Throws=10000 Same=10000 Prob=1.000000, Guess=1.000000
Coins=2 Throws=10000 Same=5003  Prob=0.500300, Guess=0.500000
Coins=3 Throws=10000 Same=2552  Prob=0.255200, Guess=0.250000
Coins=4 Throws=10000 Same=1270  Prob=0.127000, Guess=0.125000
Coins=5 Throws=10000 Same=628   Prob=0.062800, Guess=0.062500
```

This shows the probabilty of all coins falling the same way is

$2/2^{coins}$